# FME Donut Hole Extractor

Tags: polygon, fme-form

I am using FME to fill in some small holes within polygons.  I have used DonutHoleExtractor to split these out, however I have found the output via the HOLE port also brings existing 'filled' holes (valid polys that have an outershell).

How can I differentiate these??

Comment: AreaCalculator and Tester for area smaller than 0.2HA - you can also add a Attribute filter add an attribute 'hole' and filter by that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to fill the holes with the same attributes of the outershell, then you shouldn't need to use the HOLE port.  The transformer description shows a picture of the output.  The outershell is essentially a filled polygon.

Your input data may actually have valid polygons which are coincident with the holes.

Am I answering your question?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: i am only filling holes less than 0.2HA so linked the hole output to a tester

Comment: and yes the input data does have valid polys coincident with some holes (i want to retain those).  i only noticed that it output these too as i wrote 2 features out 'removed holes' and 'retained holes'

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would help to expose the format attribute fme_geometry' (use an AttributeExposer or do that in the Reader Feature Type properties dialog) then have a Tester transformer check to see if its value is 'fme_donut' or 'fme_polygon'.

Then you could filter out features that are not donuts before the DonutHoleExtractor, and you wouldn't get them mixed up in the HOLE port output.

Does that help?

Comment: thanks everyone, and thanks Mark, I was going to put a flag field in but what you suggest is better, thanks again